# jquery delay before showing

Tags: jquery, delay

I'm trying to hide something for a few seconds then show it again in jQuery.

The problem is is that my code isn't workig for some reason. Maybe the delay isn't long enough?

```
$('#mainForm').hide().delay(8000).show();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hide() will occur asynchronously.  I think what you want is something like:

```
$('#mainForm').hide('fast', function(){
  $(this).delay(8000).show('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will
>   not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not
>   use the effects queue.

So this should work:

```
$('#mainForm').hide('fast').delay(8000).show('fast');
```